# Javascript functions returning unusable value

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I'm trying to get a percentage of a value between two numbers.

Here's my code:

```
var easeMethod = 'easeOutCubic';        // Mathematical curve.
var easeTime = 1250;                    // In milliseconds.
var easeTime_Fill = easeTime + 500;     // Extra time for fills.

function clip(value, min, max)
{
    //var valueInBoundaries = Math.max(valueMin, Math.min(value, valueMax));

    if(value < min) value = min;
    if(value > max) value = max;

    return value;
}

function rangePercentage(value, min, max)
{
    value = clip(value, min, max);

    return ((value - min) * 100) / (max - min);
}

$('.fill').each(function()
{
    var valueMin = $(this).attr('data-valueMin');
    var valueMax = $(this).attr('data-valueMax');
    var value = $(this).attr('data-value');

    if(typeof value !== typeof undefined && value !== false)
    {
        if(typeof valueMin == typeof undefined || valueMin == false) valueMin = "0";
        if(typeof valueMax == typeof undefined || valueMax == false) valueMax = "100";

        var percentage = rangePercentage(value, valueMin, valueMax);

        $(this).animate({
            width: percentage + "%"
        }, easeTime_Fill, easeMethod);
    }
});
```

For some reason it won't work. When I do an `alert` it gives me the right percentage, but when I plug it into the JQuery function, nada, as if it was 0.

Comment: Should it not be `if(value > max) value = max;` instead of `<`?

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I changed it and now it's always setting it to the max value. Any idea why?

Comment: What are `easeTime_Fill` and `easeMethod`? How are they related to `rangePercentage`? Can you add a [minimal complete and verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) snippet? It will both help us to understand your problem, and future readers to see if they have a similar one. Thank you.

Comment: Your code seems to be working: https://jsfiddle.net/o73y89yt/. Are you sure you included [jquery ui](https://jqueryui.com/) to your page? `easeOutCubic` is not part of jquery alone.

Comment: Yes I am sure. That's so weird. I'm running on Chrome Canary, could that be the issue?

Comment: Is the above fiddle working for you?

Comment: Yes it is. That is so weird...

Comment: So it is not a problem with your browser. It comes from somewhere else in your page. But it is not linked to the above code.

Comment: There's nothing else that references this. There's only one fill class.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your clipping-method still has errors, therefore it converts every value < max to max.

```
function clip(value, min, max){
    //this version may behave weird if you don't pass in numbers
    //so you have to take care of the types!
    //but to me it's more readable than the min-max-version
    return value > min? value < max? value: max: min;

    //this will convert everything to numbers
    return Math.max(min, Math.min(max, value));
}

function rangePercentage(value, min, max){
    //the subtractions convert all inputs to numbers.
    //therefore this version is a bit more tolerant than clipping the value,
    //because we can ensure that we always pass numbers to clip()
    return clip( (value - min) / (max - min) * 100, 0, 100 );
}

$('.fill').each(function(){
    //don't do the same task over and over again, if you don't have to
    var $this = $(this);

    //the `+` converts everything to numbers.*
    //but it's not very flexible when dealing with leading whitespace
    //in such cases you might want to use parseFloat() instead, 
    //or trim() the string first.
    var valueMin = +$this.attr('data-valueMin');
    var valueMax = +$this.attr('data-valueMax');
    var value = +$this.attr('data-value');

    //better check wether you actually have a number, instead of
    //this big bulk of condition wich still doesn't ensure you valid inputs
    if(!isNaN(value)){
        if(isNaN(valueMin)) valueMin = 0;
        if(isNaN(valueMax)) valueMax = 100;

        var percentage = rangePercentage(value, valueMin, valueMax);
        $(this).animate({
            width: percentage + "%"
        }, easeTime_Fill, easeMethod);
    }
});
```

the `+` converts everything to numbers, but it's not very flexible when dealing with leading whitespace in such cases you might want to use parseFloat() instead, or trim() the string first.

just for conveniance

```
//to convert everything to numbers, converts NaN's to 0.
function number(value){ return +value || 0 }
function int(value){ return value | 0 } //only last 32 bits (sign + 31 bits)
function uint(value){ return value >>> 0 }  //last 32 bits
```

Comment: I agree for parsing the data attributes. However I don't see what is wrong with his clip function (though I do prefer the `Math.max` and `Math.min` approach).

Comment: In any case I am not sure you solved OP problem as his code is actually working: https://jsfiddle.net/o73y89yt/2/.

Comment: ok, he finally changed it. Last time I looked, it was still `if(value < min) value = min; if(value < max) value = max;`

Comment: Yes you're right there was a typo in the first version. However, note that typographic problems do not constitute a proper question for SO, and should not be encouraged and directly answered (comments are OK though of course).

Comment: But I suspect the attribute parsing may be OP's problem.

Comment: @Roque, maybe. Data-types are often a problem for inexperienced programmer in JS, especially String and Number, because coercion solves some problems but not all of them. Therefore I see a value in Answers even with just slight rearrangements of the code, that make it more robust, and annotations about possible pitfalls, and bad-practices  or better approaches to problems. Especially when sbd. seems to struggle even with such a trivial code.

Comment: I think you should update your answer to focus on this particular issue.

Comment: I'm going to make the changes Thomas suggested and let you all know. And Thomas you're definitely right, I'm pretty new to JavaScript as well. I've really only been an HTML/CSS programmer, only recently getting into JS

Comment: So your code worked for me. Thank you very much. You've not only helped me with my problem, but also increased my understanding of JS. Just to clarify, if I were to use trim it would go something like `+($this.attr('data-value').trim())` correct? Also, would you suggestion parseFloat() or trim() performance wise?

Comment: I spoke too soon. It's not working. Say these were my attributes: `data-value="75" data-valueMin="80" data-valueMax="100"`. The function ends up returning 80. It should be returning 0.

Comment: Once again I spoke too soon. Is working haha my bad!

Comment: `trim()` should not be necessary before parsing. JS has no problem parsing strings like `"      3.14           "` into numbers.

Comment: If you use `parseInt` or `parseFloat`, even trailing letters are not a problem: `parseFloat("  4.2whatever ") === 4.2`.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of creating a separate variable for percentage can you try to call the method inside your JQuery function?

```
$(this).animate({    
    width: rangePercentage(value, valueMin, valueMax) + "%"    
}, easeTime_Fill, easeMethod);
```